# Can two separate Windows services access the same POP mailbox simultaneously?

Tags: c#, pop3

We have got a single POP e-mail account. This e-mail account is filled with:

- mails with subject XYZ
- mails with subject ABC

*We have two Windows services*

- Service 1 - Which picks up emails with Subject XYZ only (Reads an email, stores it in the database and then deletes it from the mailbox)
- Service 2 - Which picks up emails with Subject ABC only (Reads an email, stores it in the database and then deletes it from the mailbox)

Can these two separate C# services (Service 1 & 2) (.Net framework 4.0) run simultaneously on this single POP enabled mailbox and work without any access conflicts over the mailbox?

Comment: yes, there wouldn't be a reason not to. just like on your phone, you may sync your email but also on your desktop computer - you use outlook to sync with the same email account. Same when you are say sending emails within .NET, you could be sending emails from multiple users on a website (such as notification of an order) - there will be multiple users that invoke this on your website. uses the same email account but different content perhaps to send to a different email address (but using same POP details/email server etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there is generally no restrictions on how many clients can connect with the same account sequentially.

Notes

- you should not be constantly be connecting - polling and disconnecting is the expected approach.
- you may have issues deleting items due to way POP3 addresses items - may need to synchronize deletion in some way if server does allow 2 clients for the same user to be in TRANSACTION state at the same time (unlikely).
- server may have some protection against frequent access from different IP in addition to exclusive single user access - you need to check with particular service provider if there are any restrictions (also likely for 2-3 well known clients you'd be fine).

See [POP3 RFC 1939](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, multiple processes should be able to **read** from the same mailbox simultaneously.

The caveats are

1. That the server supports simultaneous access (it should)
2. That neither process is deleting messages.

Caveat #2 is important in that both processes have to read through the list of messages to find messages that are appropriate to them, but neither process will know which messages the other process has already read.  If either process deletes a message, it opens up the possibility that one process will already know the message exists and attempt to read said message after the second process has deleted it.  (A race condition.)

A better approach might be to have a single "Mail Reader" process read all messages, enter them into different queues (perhaps stored in a database) which are then handled by the other two "Do Work" processes.  After the Mail Reader process has successfully placed the message into a queue, then it can safely delete the message from the mailbox.